# How to create a relationship between "User", "Wishlist", and "game" using many-to-many relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm struggling to create a many-to-many relationship between User, Wishlist, and Game.
Currently, my models are looks like this:

User.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_secure_password
    has_many :games, dependent: :destroy
    
    validates :first_name, presence: true
    validates :last_name, presence: true
    validates :email, presence: true
    validates :password, presence: true

    has_one_attached :profile_image
end
```

Wishlist.rb

```
class Wishlist < ApplicationRecord
   
end
```

game.rb

```
class Game < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
end
```

Right now, wishlist isn't related to other two and User and Game are related in one to many relationship. However, I want to use wishlist to connect them both with many-to-many relationship. Please help me figure this out.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me that you will need to use has_many :through:

> A has_many :through association is often used to set up a many-to-many connection with another model. This association indicates that the declaring model can be matched with zero or more instances of another model by proceeding through a third model.

Example:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :wishlists
  has_many :games, throught: :wishlists
end

class Wishlist < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :game
end

class Game < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :wishlists
  has_many :users, throught: :wishlists
end
```

Reference: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association